# How to find distinct users in multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, distinct, exists

I have a table called users that holds users ids, as well as a few tables like `cloud_storage_a`, `cloud_storage_b` and `cloud_storage_c`. If a user exists in `cloud_storage_a`, that means they are a connected to cloud storage a. A user can exist in many cloud storages too. Here's an example:

`users` table:

```
user_id | address      | name
-------------------------------
123     | 23 Oak Ave   | Melissa
333     | 18 Robson Rd | Steve
421     | 95 Ottawa St | Helen
555     | 12 Highland  | Amit
192     | 39 Anchor Rd | Oliver
```

`cloud_storage_a`:

```
user_id
-------
 421
 333
```

`cloud_storage_b`:

```
user_id
-------
 555
```

`cloud_storage_c`:

```
user_id
-------
 192
 555
```

Etc.

I want to create a query that grabs all users connected on any cloud storage. So for this example, users `421, 333, 555, 192` should be returned. I'm guessing this is some sort of join but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. Instead of a JOIN that merges tables next to each other based on a key, you want to use a UNION which stacks recordsets/tables on top of eachother.

```
SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_a
UNION
SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_b
UNION
SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_c
```

Using keyword `UNION` here will give you distinct user_id's across all three tables. If you switched that to `UNION ALL` you would no longer get Distinct, which has it's advantages in other situations (not here, obviously).

### Edited to add:

If you wanted to bring in user address you could use this thing as a subquery and join into your user table:

```
SELECT
    subunion.user_id
    user.address
FROM
    user
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_a
            UNION
            SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_b
            UNION
            SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_c
        ) subunion ON
            user.user_id = subunion.user_id
```

That union will need to grow as you add more cloud_storage_N tables. All in all, it's not a great database design. You would be much better off creating a single `cloud_storage` table and having a field that delineates which one it is `a`, `b`, `c`, ... ,`N`

Then your UNION query would just be `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM cloud_storage;` and you would never need to edit it again.

Comment: How would I include the users table? (ie what if I want to include users.address in results?)

Comment: I've added an additional query to the answer that would bring in address from the users table.

Comment: If I had a single cloud_storage table, how would I mark if a user belongs to many of those? (ie a user could be connected to a, b and c)

Comment: Then you would have three records in the single `cloud_storage` table for that user. Your `cloud_storage` table would have two fields: `user_id` and `cloud_table_name`. Your values, if `user_id` `555` belonged to all three would be: `555, a`, `555, b`, `555, c`. The nice thing here is that as you add new `cloud_table_names`, you just need a new record, instead of a new table: `555, d`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join unknown(?) number of tables `cloud_storage_X` this way.

You'd better change your schema to the following:

storage:

```
user_id cloud
------- -----
 421     a
 333     a
 555     b
 192     c
 555     c
```

Then the query is as simple as this:

```
select distinct user_id
from   storage;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.* from users u,
 cloud_storage_a csa,
 cloud_storage_b csb,
 cloud_storage_c csc 
where u.user_id = csa.user_id or u.user_id = csb.user_id or u.user_id = csc.user_id
```

You should simplify your schema to handle this type of queries.

Comment: This could return multiple rows per user, and it's more expensive than other possible query styles.

Answer (score 0):

To get columns from your `users` table for all (distinct) qualifying users:

```
SELECT * -- or whatever you need
FROM   users u
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cloud_storage_a WHERE user_id = u.user_id) OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cloud_storage_b WHERE user_id = u.user_id) OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cloud_storage_c WHERE user_id = u.user_id);
```

To just get all `user_id` and nothing else, [@JNevill's `UNION` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33245089/939860) looks good. You *could* join the result of this to `users` to the same effect:

```
SELECT u.* -- or whatever you need
FROM   users u
JOIN  (
   SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_a
   UNION
   SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_b
   UNION
   SELECT user_id FROM cloud_storage_c
   ) c USING user_id);
```

But that's probably slower.